# Как программно добавить Padding

Tags: java, android

Как программно добавить Padding в 16 API - start, top, end, bottom

Я хотел использовать `setPaddingRelative` метод, но он работает  с 17 API.

Comment: `setPaddingRelative` отличается от `setPadding` только тем, что он меняем местами `start` и `end` для локализации, в которой элементы располагаются не слева-направо, а справа налево. Все.

Answer (score 1):

А этот метод не подходит?

```
setPadding(start, top, end, bottom)
```

Или так:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
    searchView.setPaddingRelative(0 , 0, 0 , 0);
} else {
    searchView.setPadding(0 , 0, 0 , 0);
}
```

**UPD**

В исходниках посмотрел в зависимости от LayoutDirection Right-to-left или left-to-right, меняет местами значения start и end

Я думаю можно унаследоваться от View и добиться того же самого, как раз из этой статьи: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379643/android-view-setpadding-vs-setpaddingrelative

```
public void setPaddingCustom(int start, int top, int end, int bottom) {
        switch(getLayoutDirection()) {
            case LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL:
                super.setPadding(end, top, start, bottom);
                break;
            case LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR:
            default:
                super.setPadding(start, top, end, bottom);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Я точно не знаю, по моему нет, насколько я понял из http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379643/android-view-setpadding-vs-setpaddingrelative

Comment: А буедт ли так как нужно работать setPadding?

Comment: getLayoutDirection() - он возвращает направление макета? Что под этим имеется в виду?

Comment: @semiromid, да взял этот кусок прямо из исходника метода setPaddingRelative

Comment: Так стоп!  getLayoutDirection () с 17 lvl  API. Не будет работать setPaddingCustom

Comment: @semiromid  из официальной документации: Returns
LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL if the layout direction is RTL or returns LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR if the layout direction is not RTL. For compatibility, this will return LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR if API version is lower than JELLY_BEAN_MR1

Comment: А что именно имеется в виду?Это же все с 17 API будет работать

Comment: georgehardcore - Так а что это значит то что вы написали выше о вырезки из офф. документации?

Comment: @semiromid что ниже 17 версии, будет всегда возвращаться LTR

Comment: georgehardcore так getLayoutDirection() просто нету в ниже 17 API. Он там не будет просто даже работать, не будет компилироваться.

Comment: очевидно, надо юзать setPadding тогда, если ниже